# Use active model serializer with rails namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activemodel, active-model-serializers

I am in this situation,
in my controller I call:

```
render json: @customers_filtered, serializer: User::CustomerSerializer
```

My serializer:

```
class User::CustomerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,:firstname
end
```

But when I call the controller's action, it gives me:

```
Unable to autoload constant CustomerSerializer, expected /var/www/qbvault/app/serializers/customer_serializer.rb to define it
```

If I cut the `User::` from the serializer, it doesn't find the model where to read attributes from.

Is there a way to fix di behaviour? Can I set the model name on the serializer?

Comment: Try putting your serializer file in a subfolder called "user", wrap your class in a `module User` and rename your class to `class CustomerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer`.
It might be because of Rails' auto require/include magic.

Comment: It gives me: undefined method `id' for #<User::Customer::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f3f431ab678> Did you mean? #ids

Comment: But it doesn't make sense, because my customer has id...I cannot understand what is this Relation..

Comment: Whenever you see "::ActiveRecord_Relation:xxx" keep in mind that there can be more than one in that relation, meaning you do not want the id of the relation, but rather the ids of the elements IN that relation. Conveniently ActiveRecord provides you the method "ids" to get an array of ids :)

Comment: This mean that I need to use different serializers for the action like index that has a group of models, and the action like show that has only one?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not really know how to use ActiveModel::Serializer, I can't really help you there :(